# See the review menu on mobile

Tags: discussion, mobile-web

Is there an easy way to see the review menu on the mobile? or is it planned to add it.

In the past on my mobile I cheated by selecting the notification when you win the badge to review close vote, it bring to a non-mobile website layout.

Now I found the menu by following the 'full site' link at the bottom, after I can go review.

Let me know if there is an easy way ! (or if planned to add) Thanks